# POST request with a form action on another page returns 405, doesn't process request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-views

The idea is to display a search box, where a user can type in the address, which get's completed by Google Autocomplete. Then, we save the lat and long parameters and redirect to the `/search` (using POST) or (maybe use a GET request) alternatively `/search?lat=xxx&long=xxx`.

For the second case, with URL parameters I could use `lat = request.GET('lat')`

My **Index.html form**

```
<form action="{% url 'users:index' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="cityname" name="cityname" />
<input type="hidden" id="Lat" name="Lat" />
<input type="hidden" id="Lng" name="Lng" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When user picks from the dropdown, the javascript gives me values of `Lat` , `Lng` and `cityname`. Upon submit, they are redirected to `/users/`, which is a ListView and has the following **views.py**

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    # context_object_name = 'latest_teacher_list'
    model = Teacher
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST' and 'Lat' in self.request.POST:
            if self.request.POST['Lat'] != '':
                lat = self.request.POST['Lat']
            else:
                lat = None
        else:
            lat = None
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['teacher_list'] = Teacher.objects.all()[:5]
        context['lat'] = lat

        return context
```

However, this gives me a blank page when I submit the form. When `form action` is blank, it submits the form to the same page, and correctly displays Lat, Long. But when form action is `/users/` it gives me a 405 error.

Is such thing possible, or do I need to do a GET request, e.g. pass the URL parameters as a link, so instead of a form, I will simply have a link to:

```
users?lat=xxx&long=xxx
```

where I have to use Js to populate xxx somehow

Comment: Did you define the Post method in your view?

Comment: I think this could be the problem... let me check

Comment: This response code (405) can come from any number of issues, but it generally ends up that either you are using the wrong URL or using Wrong request method.

Comment: I have from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpRequest which is grey (not used anywhere)

Comment: Any errors in the terminal ?

Comment: I have the following error msg: Method Not Allowed (POST): /users/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153368/discussion-between-webguy-and-roma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView` does not have a `post` method defined, therefore it will return status code 405 for post requests.

You could define a `post` method which simply calls the view's `get()` method:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Allow post requests for form submissions"""
        return super(IndexView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you recommend using GET or is POST better for such cases?

Comment: Since you're not modifying data, a GET request would be ok for this search form.

Comment: One more thing, should I add a form to forms.py and validate it similar to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Yes, a Django form might be useful in this view. It could take care of validation that `Lat` and `Long` are floats/decimals within the required range.

Answer (score 1):

You must define post method, but you can always set the form method to GET. That is even the more correct way for a search box because GET is used for getting data, POST for giving data the server has to store or something, PUT is for updating data. So you should use GET as your form method. Also if you use GET as method the browsers back and forward buttons will also contain the 'lat', 'long' parameters so you will have working back and forward buttons. No link generation will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have an form in html, but your view only handles get requests, you have to update it and inherit FormView or add post function with all the form handling code.